# Solving Numerical four coupled differential equations using Runge-Kutta

Tags: python, numeric, differential-equations, runge-kutta

How can I solve the following four coupled equations numerically in Python?

I need a source code !!!!!

```
y'(1) = (-wa+wp)*y(2)+g*y(4)
y'(2) = (-wa+2wp)*y(1)-g*y(3)
y'(3) = (wa-wp)*y(4)+g*y(2)
y'(4) =-(wa+wp)*y(3)-g*y(1)
```

Comment: What are your experiences with numerical solvers? Is it the whole concept, or just the python language? Making the index shift so that the array starts at index `0`?

Comment: I have no experience in numerical solutions

Comment: Were you just introduced to the whole topic of differential equations, or is that in some distant past and you recently found yourself with the necessity of finding a numerical solution? Do you recognize the system as linear and know that you can expect exponentially growing or falling solutions, possibly oscillating?

Comment: I have enough information about differential equations, for now I just want to solve the above equations numerically.

Comment: Per the answer you found out about scipy.integrate, there are also scikit and pyDStool and others (jitcode as extension of scipy,...). From the documentation, do you understand how to encode a first-order system so that it can be passed to the solver routine?

Comment: I did not understand some parts

Comment: Please _add_ to the question text what sources you consulted, what parts you understood and what parts not. In the end the solution is rather straight-forward, but you learn better if you research it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Integration and ODEs (scipy.integrate)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html). Exactly which solver you use will depend upon the boundary conditions you have: particularly solve_ivp for initial value problems and solve_bvp for boundary value problems.